# Payload in Java mule application

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

If I have two separate mule flows that would run synchronously

```
    <flow name="GatherDDICollection" doc:name= "GatherDDICollection" processingStrategy="synchronous" >
       <poll doc:name= "Poll" frequency ="5000">
         <invoke object-ref="numberInformationCollectionFlow" method="popWaiting" doc:name="PopPending"/>
       </poll>
       <expression-filter expression="#[payload != null &amp;&amp; ((payload instanceof org. mule.transport. NullPayload) == false) &amp;&amp; payload.size() > 0 ]" doc:name ="HasRequest"/>      
       <logger message= "Collection request - #[payload]" level= "INFO" doc:name="Logger" />       
    </flow >

    <flow name= "ProvisionDDI" doc:name ="ProvisionDDI" processingStrategy="synchronous" >
       <poll doc:name="Poll" frequency="5000" >
        <invoke object-ref="numberInformationCollectionFlow" method="getParentDdis" doc:name= "DataToProvision"/>
       </poll>             
       <expression-filter expression="#[payload != null &amp;&amp; ((payload instanceof org. mule.transport. NullPayload) == false) &amp;&amp; payload > 0]" doc:name="HasDataToProvision" />     
       <logger message= "DDI to provision- #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name= "Logger"/>           
    </flow >
```

Would the payload get confused which flow it belongs to? 
I ask because I am confuse with the current scenario:
The first flow (GatherDDICollection) will not show "Collection request -.." because method "popWaiting" returns null.
The second flow (ProvisionDDI) should show "DDI to provision .." because te method "getParentDdis" returns a list of objects but it doesn't (I know this because if I remove the expression-filter on the second flow, the logger shows the message . Is this because it is getting confused with the payload from the first flow?

Comment: 2 different mule messages --> 2 different payloads, these are independent. Your second expression has a typo: payload > 0 --> payload.size() > 0

Comment: Oh wow this is embarassing. I must have been staring at it for too long and not noticed. Thank you so much !

Comment: Has this question been solved ?